# Matching regular expression on comma or space, but not both

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to have a regular expression that replaces commas and spaces with a comma and a space, but leaves it alone if it's already a comma and a space in sequence.

Example:

44,55 90 should turn into 44, 55, 90

but, 44, 55, 90 when entered again should remain the same.

I initially tried `/[\s,]/g` but it of course replaces any comma or space with both a comma and space, so 44, 55, 90 became 44, , 55, , 90

Comment: /, ?/g try this

Comment: can you please add a language tag to the question

Comment: @MaciejKozieja that works for commas, but not spaces.

Comment: /, ?|,/g now it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is very simple `/ ,?|,/g`
Or if you want to remove any amount of white space before comma `/ *,?| /g`
Or if you want go crazy go with this `/\s*,\s*|\s+/g` this will replace any extra spacing before , and after it and do all good stuf as erlier.

Comment: The only way this answer is valid is if every string is assumed to only be a mix of numbers, commas, and spaces. There's no digit-specificity in this answer.

Comment: True but that was the question

Comment: It was the example string, not the whole breadth of the question, and my comment was a _comment_, not a contradiction. I'm assuming people wanting help with a simple regex might want to know how limited the answer is that they're copying, especially when the desired matches are specified to be digits.

Comment: It matches too many things to avert the caveat. But it's your answer, and the accepted one. My intent was to warn the OP and anyone else that the answer has a narrow scope of usefulness. Whether or not that's relevant is completely contextual per-string checked. https://regex101.com/r/3FnGgW/2

Comment: "that replaces commas and spaces with a comma and a space"

Comment: Aha! You're right. I missed that _lack_ of digit specificity and tunnel-focused on the test string.

Comment: I totaly see your point but question was simple so it neaded simple answer :D

Comment: The input will be only numbers.

Comment: @MaciejKozieja There seems to be an issue when adding spaces before commas, do you happen to know why that is or how to fix it? `44 ,55` becomes `44, , 55`

Comment: @qbolt yes thats my mistake i didn't thougt about this but this should work `\s*,\s*|\s+`

Comment: @MaciejKozieja Haha that fixed that issue, but now commas don't work by themselves. `44,55` should become `44, 55`.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for the test string, assuming you're looking to fix strings with digits, commas and spaces, and not other combinations of characters.

Search for this:

`\d(,)\d|\d([ ]{1,},[ ]{0,})\d|\d([ ]{1,})\d`

Replace capture group 1 with comma `,` and a space, .

That should handle any real or potential white space with quantifiers checking for multiple whitespaces.

[Test string with 6 matches](https://regex101.com/r/w7Osv6/2):

`44,55 90 ,44 , 55   ,    90  , 1234 ,`

Answer (score 0):

You could go the other way and replace everything that is not digits with anything you want, using a negated character class:

```
'999 123,098b7b7b7b7b,,,123^&*()43'.replace(/[^\d]+/g,', ');
//"999, 123, 098, 7, 7, 7, 7, 123, 43"
```